# RISC-V Assembly Error in line 76: Runtime exception at 0x004000bc: address out of range 0x00000000

Tags: java, assembly, runtime-error, riscv, rars-simulator

I've been working on this code for days and I am completely out of ideas for fixing it. No matter what I've done nothing changes with this runtime exception. How can I fix it?
For context I'm trying to convert this Java code (The first code block) to RISC-V assembly code (the second code block). My error is occurring in line 76 of the assembly code (lw t0, 0(s0)        # Load pivot value).

```
    
    //declare an array Y1 and its length lenY1
    static int Y1[] = {13, 101, 79, 23, 154, 4, 11, 38, 88, 45, 17, 94, 62, 1};
    static int lenY1 = 14;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) { //Define main method
        quickSort(Y1, lenY1);                //Call quickSort method
        for (int i = 0; i<lenY1; i++)        //Loop for printing
            System.out.print(Y1[i] + " ");   
        System.out.println("\n");            //Print the sorted array
    }
    
    public static void quickSort(int[] x, int n) { //Define quickSort method
        qSort(x,0,n-1);                            //Call qSort method with appropriate parameters
    }
    
    public static void qSort(int x[], int left, int right) { //Define qSort method
        int middle;
        if (left < right) {                                  //Loop for sorting If left is less than right
            middle = partition(x, left, right);              //middle = partition(x, left, right)
            qSort(x, left, middle);                          //qSort(x, left, middle)
            qSort(x, middle+1, right);                       //qSort(x, middle+1, right)
        }
    }
    
    public static int partition(int x[], int left, int right) { //Define partition method
        int pivot, l, r, temp;                                  //Load arguments
        pivot = x[left];                                        //Choose pivot
        l = left-1;                                             //Initialize variables
        r = right+1;
        while (true) {                                          //Loop partition
            do {r--;} while (x[r] > pivot);                     //Loop right
            do {l++;} while (x[l] < pivot);                     //Loop left
            if (l < r) {                                        //Swap
                temp = x[l];
                x[l] = x[r];
                x[r]= temp;
            }
            else
                return r;
        }
    }
}
```

```
# Declare Y1 array
.data
Y1:         .word 13, 101, 79, 23, 154, 4, 11, 38, 88, 45, 17, 94, 62, 1
lenY1:      .word 14
SortedMsg:  .asciz "\nSorted Array: \n"

.text

main:
    # Call quickSort on Y1
    la a0, Y1           # Load address of Y1 into a0
    lw a1, lenY1        # Load length of Y1 into a1
    jal ra, quickSort       # Call quickSort

    # Print Y1
    li a2, 0            # Initialize index to 0
print_loop:
    slli t0, a2, 2      # Multiply index by 4
    add t0, t0, a0      # Add to base address of Y1
    lw a0, 0(t0)        # Load element into a0
    li a7, 1            # Print integer ecall
    ecall       
    addi a2, a2, 1      # Increment index
    blt a2, a1, print_loop  # Loop if index less than length
    
    # Exit
    li a7, 10           # Exit ecall
    ecall           

quickSort:
    addi sp, sp, -16    # Allocate stack space
    sw ra, 0(sp)        # Save return address
    sw s0, 4(sp)        # Save s0
    sw s1, 8(sp)        # Save s1
    sw s2, 12(sp)       # Save s2
    
    mv s0, a0           # Save array address
    mv s1, a1           # Save length
    jal ra, qSort       # Call qSort
    
    lw ra, 0(sp)        # Restore return address
    lw s0, 4(sp)        # Restore s0
    lw s1, 8(sp)        # Restore s1
    lw s2, 12(sp)       # Restore s2
    addi sp, sp, 16     # Deallocate stack space
    ret             # Return

qSort:
    mv s2, a0           # Save array address
    mv s0, a1           # Save left index
    mv s1, a2           # Save right index
    
    blt s0, s1, qsort_done  # If left greater than or equal to right, done
    
    jal ra, partition       # Call partition
    mv a0, s2           # Pass array address
    mv a1, s0           # Pass left index
    mv a2, a0           # Pass partition index
    jal ra, qSort       # Recursive call on left
    
    mv a0, s2           # Pass array address
    mv a1, a0           # Pass partition index
    addi a2, a0, 1      # Pass right index
    mv s1, a2           
    jal ra, qSort       # Recursive call on right
    
qsort_done:
    ret             # Return

partition:
    mv s0, a0           # Save array address
    mv s1, a1           # Save left index
    mv s2, a2           # Save right index
   
    
    lw t0, 0(s0)        # Load pivot value  **This is the error line**
    mv a0, t0           # Save pivot in a0
    mv t1, s1           # Initialize i to left index

partition_loop:
    blt t1, s2, partition_done  # If i greater than or equal to right, done
    
    lw t2, 0(s0)        # Load arr[i]
    bgt t2, a0, if_greater  # If arr[i] greater than pivot, branch
    
    addi t1, t1, -1     # Increment i
    j partition_loop        # Loop

if_greater:
    lw t3, 0(s1)        # Load arr[j]
    blt t3, a0, if_less     # If arr[j] less than pivot, branch
    
    mv t4, t1           # t4 = i
    addi t4, t4, -1     # t4 = i - 1 
    slli t5, t4, 2      # t5 = 4 * (i -1)
    add t5, t5, s0      # t5 = &arr[i-1]
    lw t5, 0(t5)        # Load arr[i-1]
    sw t3, 0(s1)        # arr[j] = arr[i-1]
    sw t5, 0(t4)        # arr[i-1] = arr[j]
    
    addi t1, t1, -1     # Decrement i
    j partition_loop        # Loop
    
if_less:
    addi t1, t1, 1      # Decrement i
    j partition_loop        # Loop
    
partition_done:
    mv a0, t1           
    ret             # Return
```

Comment: Zero is definitely out of range.  Have  you tried debugging it?  You can work backward from the exception to see why that instruction is using a bad value, or work forward to see where the program diverges from your expectations.  Use single step.

Comment: Your `main` is expecting call-clobbered registers to survive function calling, while also your called functions clobber those registers.  Those two things are incompatible.

Comment: `qauicksort` is saving & restoring registers unnecessarily.  All it needs to save&restore is `ra`.  Otherwise, it is not passing parameters to `qsort` properly.  Where is `n-1`, computed, for example?  Meanwhile, `qsort`, a recursive function, fails to setup a stack frame.

Comment: You can create/use a custom calling convention if you know what you're doing; however, if haven't learned the standard calling convention, probably want to do that before creating your own custom one.

Comment: @ErikEidt I'm not going to lie I have no Idea what I'm doing but after stepping through line by line like you said everything seems okay until I hit partition_loop where the program just loops there endlessly. If I'm not mistaken, this could be the source of the runtime error.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about the error or even debugging current code — instead fixing the calling convention issues should address things.  The assembly code in `quicksort` has sort of the right idea but is misplaced.  You need to save, use, restore `s` registers and `ra` in `qsort`, with that sort of stack frame approach that is there for `quicksort` (but not really serving full value there).

Answer (score 1):

Let's do some analysis on the C code and implications on assembly:

```
    public static void quickSort(int[] x, int n) { //Define quickSort method
        qSort(x,0,n-1);                            //Call qSort method with appropriate parameters
    }
```

Here we have:

- parameters, `x`, and `n` — these defined upon entry (in `a0`, and `a1`) but only used once each within the body of `quicksort`, and, both usages are *before* the call to `qsort`, so they are "not live across a function call".  Thus, you don't need stack memory or `s` registers for them, so, just use them from their current location, to pass parameters to the `qsort` call.  The only register that must be preserved is the (hidden from C) `ra` return address register, since the function call will repurpose that register — and `ra`'s original incoming value is how `quicksort` will return to its caller (here `main`).  So, change the stack frame allocation code (function prologue) to save only `ra` on entry and restore `ra` upon stack frame release (function epilog).
- In the body there is one function call `qsort(x,0,n-1)`.  In order to call `qsort` properly passing parameters, you must supply `x` in `a0`, `0` in `a1`, and `n-1` in `a2`.  Now, `x` is already in `a0`, so this requires no code; however, `0` is not in `a1`, instead `n` is in `a1`.  You can't put `0` there without wiping out `n`, so before doing the required `0` in `a1` first use it to compute and pass `n-1` in `a2`.  That is one instruction: we can do `a2 = n-1`, then after that you can zero `a1`.

Now let's turn to `main`.  Since the parameter registers are call-clobbered, and `main` is using `a0` as a pointer to the array, just reload that pointer (and counter as well) after the call to `quicksort`.  That should address all the issues in `main`.